# can i use python on ToradexT30 with embedded linux?

Tags: python

I want to develop an embedded systems using [Toradex Colibri T30](http://www.toradex.com/products/colibri-arm-computer-modules/colibri-t30), i want to use python to program this device to interface [GPS module](http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=424),hmc5883l compass and servo motors and i will be doing image processing with a usb camera module attached, summing up finally i want to use python(image processing compass,gps,pwm modules) to do all the above said stuff? is it possible? How to do? i tried online and got some results for cross compiling for embedded linux, will this cross compiling work for ARM Cortex A9 processor on ColibriT30 board? can anyone please throw some light on this doubt.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python runs on various embedded platforms](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython). E.g. [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) project is an umbrella project for cross-compiling and distributing Linux for various embedded platforms, including ARM. They provide "full" and minimal Python ports (not sure how much ROM and other resources your board has).

What I would look is that

- What embedded Linux distributions your board uses
- How I can get distribution X on it
- Then just install Python using the distribution package manager

Comment: yeah..it uses angstorm distribution